# how to do templating on Drupal

Tags: drupal

I'm new in drupal and I'm kinda stuck on my project. So I come here ask for help.

I want to develop my website in drupal with template concepts. My webpages have a lot similar style "blocks" but in different contents (like pictures or wordings).

I started with custom block for each section on my page with unique content type and then assemble them into a page with page manager. After 3 pages the content type and contents become too messy and I think I have lost control on the complexity. Also it's kinda stupid trying to create a custom block for every section.

So now I'm trying to develop / config a custom block, which has its own style and js, that can filter on content type and select specific content to render.

I tried to create a custom block type with content reference. but it does not show full post but a link to the content. I try to code a custom block but I'm not sure how to dynamically pass content into it. Could you please provide any idea or shine any hint on me?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can show full content in the custom block by setting block display without any code.

Go to `Admin menu` > `Structure` > `Block layout` > `Block types` > `Your block type` > `Operations` > `Manage display`:

[image]

With reference content field, set `Format` to "Rendered entity" and `View mode` to "Full content":

[image]